# VSCode breakpoints grayed out

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, pascal

I have a single project in VSCode where breakpoints are not working and I can't figure out why. I'm new to VSCode but I've got them to work in other projects (Pascal) but there's something about this one it doesn't like.

Does anyone at least know what this means when the break points are gray like this? Is it a bug? In the 2nd screenshot you can see I can run LLDB from the terminal on the same executable so it's not LLDB messing up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe vscode only likes gdb ?

Comment: Hey Marco. It's something with the fact the code is Objective Pascal/Cocoa. It works perfectly well if the project is pure Pascal. I haven't tried VSCode with GDB yet but GDB is basically dead on Mac at this point.

Comment: Maybe the debugger must be set to objective C (compatible) or so.  I don't use Mac myself though

Comment: It works from the command line so I think it's VSCode related. Looking again now I see I'm getting an error in the console: ERROR: Error while trying to enter break state. Debugging will now stop. Unrecognized format of field "threads" in result: result-class: done.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an obvious answer, but it's what solved the issue for me when I encountered it.

Recompile the program and try again